# Inverting two lines in a group of 3 repeating

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a txt file like this

```
AAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCC

DDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEEE
FFFFFFFFFFF

GGGGGGGGGGG
HHHHHHHHHHH
IIIIIIIIIII
```

groups of 3 lines with a line feed between.

I want to invert the first two lines of each group, making the file like this

```
BBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAA
CCCCCCCC

EEEEEEEEEEE
DDDDDDDDDDD
FFFFFFFFFFF

HHHHHHHHHHH
GGGGGGGGGGG
IIIIIIIIIII
```

how do I do that from terminal?

EDIT: I have uploaded a sample of my text file to [here](http://textuploader.com/dc0kt) if you need to test your answer against it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat -n ip.txt 
     1  AAAAAAAAAA
     2  BBBBBBBBBB
     3  CCCCCCCC
     4  
     5  DDDDDDDDDDD
     6  EEEEEEEEEEE
     7  FFFFFFFFFFF
     8  
     9  GGGGGGGGGGG
    10  HHHHHHHHHHH
    11  IIIIIIIIIII
```

Since it is a fixed format, use modulo operator accordingly

```
$ awk 'NR%4==1{s=$0; next} 1; NR%4==2{print s}' ip.txt
BBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAA
CCCCCCCC

EEEEEEEEEEE
DDDDDDDDDDD
FFFFFFFFFFF

HHHHHHHHHHH
GGGGGGGGGGG
IIIIIIIIIII
```

and a `perl` regex version for fun

```
perl -00 -pe 's/(\N+\n)(\N+\n)/$2$1/' ip.txt
```

- `-00` paragraph mode, similar to awk's `-v RS=`
- then interchange first two lines

  - can also use `(\N+\n)((?1))` - useful if complicated regex needs to be repeated

Comment: for some reason both your answers go well up to a certain point of my text file and then stops... I am trying to discover why. If you want to try, [here is a  sample of my text file](http://textuploader.com/dc0kt)

Comment: discover the problem on my text file... your perl version is working for me. Thanks

Comment: I checked it, seems like you had space in some of the empty lines... but in that case, my `awk` version is correct because it doesn't rely on paragraphs.. and indeed when I checked, `perl` version gave wrong answer...

Answer (score 2):

One way - with GNU awk:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS=""; OFS=FS="\n"} {tmp = $2; $2 = $1; $1 = tmp; ORS=RT} 1' file
BBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAA
CCCCCCCC

EEEEEEEEEEE
DDDDDDDDDDD
FFFFFFFFFFF

HHHHHHHHHHH
GGGGGGGGGGG
IIIIIIIIIII
```

Comment: Only `awk` works too.

Comment: @muhammad I guess it depends what you mean by "only awk" - the version of `mawk` that I have doesn't know about `RT` for example

Comment: for some reason your code messes with the spaces between the groups of lines... you can test it against a sample of my text file [here](http://textuploader.com/dc0kt)

Comment: @SpaceDog what flavor and version of awk are you using?

Comment: 1) Why `RS=""` separates records by the empty line? I was expected, that it wouldn't separate records at all, because `RS` variable was assigned to the empty string. In other words it doesn't have any value, so the whole input file should be processed as the one, large record. 2) How the `RT` variable works?

Comment: I found answer to the second question - [Record Splitting with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawk-split-records.html). But the first question is still actual.

Comment: @MiniMax the empty record separator trick is described here [Multiple-Line Records](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html) (sometimes referred to as *paragraph mode*)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n 'h; n; G; N; p; n; p' input.txt
```

**Explanation**

The `sed` has two operational spaces - the hold space and the pattern space. They are like two variables - `var_1` and `var_2`. The each input line goes into the pattern space, but you can copy (it replaces all content of the hold space) or append it to the hold space. Thus:

- `h` - copies the pattern space to the hold space.  Now, both the pattern and hold spaces are: `AAAAA`.
- `n` - gets the next line of input into the pattern space. So, the pattern space is now: `BBBBB`.
- `G` - appends a newline and the content of the hold space (`AAAAA`) to the pattern space so the pattern space is now `BBBBB\nAAAAA`.
- `N` - appends a newline and the next line of input to the pattern space - `BBBBB\nAAAAA\nCCCCC`
- `p` - prints the pattern space.
- `n` - gets the next line of input into the pattern space, if it exists and exits otherwise (if the end of file was reached).
- `p` - prints the pattern space again.

**Output**

```
BBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAA
CCCCCCCC

EEEEEEEEEEE
DDDDDDDDDDD
FFFFFFFFFFF

HHHHHHHHHHH
GGGGGGGGGGG
IIIIIIIIIII
```

Comment: what magic is that? It would be great if you give us some explanation.

Comment: @muhammad Explanation added.